# Where can I find the solutions to the problems in the book "An Introduction to Computational Learning Theory"?

Tags: reference-request, computational-learning-theory, books, pac-learning

I have been going through "An Introduction to Computational Learning Theory" (Kearns-Vazirani). I don't know if my solutions to the problems are correct and have no other way of checking my learning. How would I find solutions to compare to or otherwise check my learning?

Comment: You could also try asking a specific question about your specific problem/solution.